# How to merge rows with duplicate uniqe key on update in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have following table structure:

```
 +------------------+        +---------------------+
 | Users            |        | Data                |
 +------------------+        +---------------------+
 | id  |  uname_UK  |        | id |user_id_FK |data|
 +-----|------------|        +---------------------+
 | 1   |  foobar    |        | 1  |     1     | aa |
 | 2   |  bazqui    +<-------+ 2  |     3     | bb |
 | 3   |  foobaz    |        | 3  |     2     | cc |
 +------------------+        | 4  |     2     | dd |
                             +---------------------+
```

The problem now is, that during storing data in database there was typo. The user named `foobaz` should be named `foobar`. The `uname` column has a Unique constraint.

My question is how to easily fix this problem? When I update the username table, I get error - duplicate uniqe key, as expected. In the end I would like to have the foreign keys updated too.

My idea was do some trigger magic, but I was hoping there would be some more elegant solution. Another constraint here is, that the update is initiated through frontend, so I cannot use PHP.

Alternate way would be to drop the Unique constraint and make some cron job, to periodically update the database and remove the duplicate entries.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just delete the record? Update all data to the user you want to keep and delete the obsolete user.

In Oracle you can do this using the `merge into` statement. I don't know if that is possible to do in one statement in MySQL, but you might as well execute a separate delete for it. You can make it trigger magic, but I doubt if it's a good decision to always autmagically merge the users. The new username might be a typo too.

So in a normal application, if this would happen so often, I would make a 'merge users' functionality that lets you do just this.

Comment: The problem is, I don't have control over the front-end I have access only to database side.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do, is figure out what it means to your data that two users are actualy one. In *this* case, since there are two records in `Data` for user ID 2, it seems as if it's okay for users to have several records in `Data` and you can just

```
UPDATE data 
SET user_id_FK = 1
WHERE user_id_FK = 3;

DELETE FROM users
WHERE id = 3;
```

In general, you need to figure this out at an application level.
What if there's a foo counter for each user? You should probably add the value from the user you'll be deleting to the value you're keeping.
What if a user has an address?
What if a user can only have one e-mail address and your duplicate user has a different one? Which do you keep?

This is not an easy question with a general answer.